# mvc 4 - how can i get info from the model in the common layout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, layout, model

i have an unsubscribe page that using the common layout.

in the common layout there is a logo of our company, and every page that related to him - show our logo.

because we're providing a white label services - we need to check if the subsciber that reached to this page is'nt our cliet and he should not see our logo.

what I need to do is to check in the common layout from whice account the subscriber has arrived to the unsubscribe page.

is there a way to read info from the model in the common layout even though he is only a pipe to the target page?

this is the code in the common layout but the check that we're making is'nt enough and we need to check in the DB.

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:20px;">
    @if (Request.Url.PathAndQuery.ToLower().Contains("xxx") && !Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("x.x.x.x"))
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 visible-md visible-lg"></div>
            <div id="headLine" class="col-md-6">
                @if (this.Culture == "eng")
                {
                    <img src="@Url.Content("~/content/images/logoeng.png")" alt="" />
                }
                else
                {
                    <img src="@Url.Content("~/content/images/logo.png")" alt="" />
                }
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 visible-md visible-lg"></div>
        </div>
    }
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

tnk

Answer (score 0):

You could either make a call in the layout to another action that would generate the HTML needed for the logo, from an action method returning a `PartialView`.  E.g.:

```
@Html.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController", new { clientId = Model.ClientId })
```

Or the simplest way might be to set the source of the image via the `ViewBag`, which you can set in the controller, then use in your layout:

```
<img src="@ViewBag.ClientLogoSrc" alt="@ViewBag.ClientLogoAlt" />
```